# data source instance has not been supplied for the data source dataset1 in vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, report

I have a problem with MySql and reports in vb.net. I have already installed MySql ODBC and my project is already connected to the database. But I receive this error "data source instance has not been supplied for the data source dataset1".

I'm new with vb.net reports and any help will be appreciated. Thank you.Attached to this is my code for loading my data.

```
 If con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then

        Dim ds As New DataSet1
        Dim com As New MySqlCommand("select * from tb_course", con)
        Using da As New MySqlDataAdapter(com)
            da.Fill(ds)
        End Using 

        ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ProcessingMode.Local

        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = System.Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\Report1.rdlc"

        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(New Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource("DataSet1_DataTable1", ds.Tables(0)))

        ReportViewer1.DocumentMapCollapsed = True

        Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()

    End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give the dataset name and table name

I am going to give you code which is work on my Machine Correctly

```
   
Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim RpDs1 As New Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource
    Dim SQL As String = "select * from mfcount"
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(SQL, My.Settings.trialConnectionString)
    da.Fill(ds, "mfcount")
    dt = ds.Tables(0)
    ReportViewer1.Reset()
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
    RpDs1.Name = "trialDataSet4_MFCount"
    RpDs1.Value = dt
    ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = WinForms.ProcessingMode.Local
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(RpDs1)
    Dim path = New DirectoryInfo(Application.StartupPath).Parent.Parent.Parent.FullName
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = Application.StartupPath & "\Report\" & "ADDRESSReport.rdlc"
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Application.StartupPath & "\Report\" & "ADDRESSReport.rdlc"
    ReportViewer1.ZoomMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ZoomMode.PageWidth
    ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
```

This code will help you..

Comment: This would work pretty fine if you are using microsoft ODBC connection.I am using MySql connection. But this have helped me solved my problem. using your codes supplied to this query, and a little modification with the codes so it would run in mysql connection, now i finally have my report functioning well. thanks a lot @basuraj kumbhar.

Answer (score 0):

thanks  basuraj kumbhar for your help to solve this problem. Here is the working codes for MyCql connection Report in vb.net

```
Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim RpDs1 As New Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource
    Dim SQL As String = "select * from tb_course"
    Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter(SQL, con)

    da.Fill(ds, "tb_course")
    dt = ds.Tables(0)
    ReportViewer1.Reset()
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
    RpDs1.Name = "DataSet1"
    RpDs1.Value = dt
    ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ProcessingMode.Local

    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = System.Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\Report1.rdlc"
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(New Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource("DataSet1", ds.Tables(0)))

    ReportViewer1.ZoomMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ZoomMode.PageWidth
    ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
```